# Android Studio returns error "Installation failed due to: ''cmd package install-create..."

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, apk, android-debug

I'm working on an Android App in Android Studio.

After updating Android Studio to Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 2 it has stopped working.

[image: Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 2]

Now I get the following error:

[image]

> Installation did not succeed.
> The application could not be installed.
>
> List of apks:
> [0] 'D:\Filer\Dokument\...\app\build\intermediates\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
> Installation failed due to: ''cmd package install-create -r -t --user current --full --dont-kill -S 4617721' returns error 'Unknown failure: cmd: Can't find service: package''
> Retry
> Failed to launch an application on all devices

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is most likely with the Android Emulator in Android Studio.

If you do a `Cold Reboot` of the Android Emulator it will most likely solve your problem.

1. Open the Android Studio Device Manager from `Tools` -> `Device Manager`.
2. Close the Android Emulator if still running.
   [image: Close Android Emulator]
3. Click on the Android Emulator's Device Menu `▼` located on the right hand side in the Device Mananger and Choose `Cold Boot Now`.
   [image: Device Menu]

Now, try to run the app again...

Comment: Fantastic, that worked...